# The type initializer for 'Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer' threw an exception

Tags: c#-4.0, oauth-2.0

I am accessing google analytics data using Oauth 2. When I try to execute the following code, this error occurs:

> The type initializer for `'Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer'`
>   threw an exception.

Here is my code:

```
string clientid = "my client id";
string clientsecret = "my client secret";

var client = new WebServerClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, clientid, clientsecret);

var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(client, Authenticate);

var asv = new Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    Authenticator = auth,
});

var request = asv.Data.Ga.Get("ga:" + "my ProfileID", "2012-01-01", "2012-02-20", "ga:visits");
var report = request.Fetch();

private IAuthorizationState Authenticate(WebServerClient client)
{
    IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new string[] {}) { RefreshToken = "my refresh token" };
    client.RefreshToken(state);
    return state;
}
```

Comment: The stack trace should shown an inner exception explaining *which* exception was thrown during the type initializer. Edit that into your question (and tidy up the code formatting at the same time).

Comment: InnerException = {"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json.Net35, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Newtonsoft.Json.Net35, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken...                                    but i have included using Newtonsoft.Json;

Comment: Okay, well there you go - it's looking for that file, and presumably you haven't copied it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace which i was importing `using Newtonsoft.Json`
was the older version. Then i imported the new version of `Newtonsoft.Json` `(Version=4.0.2.0)`. Now its working ...........

Comment: care to elaborate on how?

Comment: I found the Dll in the packages folder under my project. It didn't change anything (same error still)

Answer (score 2):

I have documented my experience to solve this problem for `YouTube Data API v3`, please see full details below:

FYI I am using Visual Studio 2012, and .Net solution is consists of `Asp.NET` Web Application and Class Library projects. I have referenced `Google Data API` v3 in my Class Library project.

- Make sure you have installed latest `Google.Apis.YouTube.v3` Client Library from the Nuget manager.
- Update all pending packages from the `Nuget` manager.
- Delete all files from the bin folders (from both projects).
- Delete `Newtonsoft.Json` reference from the web application project if exist.
- Delete following line from the `packages.config` of web application project if exist:

  ```
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.0.8" targetFramework="net45" />
  ```
- Add the following into the web.config of web application project:

  ```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.20.0" newVersion="4.2.20.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.13.0" newVersion="1.2.13.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.168.0" newVersion="1.0.168.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below code, which may help you, its working fine for me.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            // Setting up webserver client by providing your application clientid,client secretid which are we registered in google api (cloud) console.
            var client = new WebServerClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, "Your ClientID", "Client Secret");

            // Authenticating the Web server client and GA account by passing the long lived refresh token 
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(client, Authenticate);

            // Initialize the Google analytics service.
            // Set the auth parameter to Authenticator in Google analytics service instance
            var asv = new Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.AnalyticsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                Authenticator = auth
            });

            // Preparing the query request  for Google api
            string queryDate = "";
            queryDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var request = asv.Data.Ga.Get("ga:" + "Your profileid", queryDate, queryDate, "ga:visits,ga:newVisits,ga:bounces,ga:pageviews,ga:timeOnSite,ga:transactionsPerVisit");
            // Adding dimensions
            request.Dimensions = "ga:date";
            // Fecthing data
            var data = request.Fetch();



        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }




    private static IAuthorizationState Authenticate(WebServerClient client)
    {
        // The refresh token which application captures called as long lived refresh token, and will be used for gat new access token in future.
        // In Json format access token and refresh token will be captured and saved in database when user allowd our application to access his analytics data.
        // Next time when we are going to access the google analytics data for that user load the refresh token
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new string[] { }) { RefreshToken = "your refresh token" };

        // Refresh the access token by passing the long lived refreshed token
        client.RefreshToken(state);

        // return the IAutherizationSate result
        return state;
    }
```

Note: you have to get the refresh token before using these methods

Answer (score 0):

I had this error, but my solution was a little different.  I was using Visual Studio 2017 and I had the current version (at the time) of Newtonsoft.Json installed (11.0.2).  When I installed the current version of the Google.Apis (1.35.1), I received the error "The type initializer for 'Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer' threw an exception".  When looking at the inner exception information I found that the Google.Apis was expecting Newtonsoft.Json version 10.  I removed Newtonsoft and Google.Apis and then reinstalled google.apis via nuget.  Version 10 of Newtonsoft.Json was also installed and the error went away.

If anyone is also having this error, make sure the version of Newtonsoft that is expected by the google api is actually installed.